# Filtering lines of a bunch of text files with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been trying to filter out some lines of a bunch of text files. It's been working for me when I am processing one file at the time, but when I try to load a directory, it stops working as intended. Therefore, I think I am missing something here. This is the code

```
  def nameRegexp: String = { "\\s{14,25}([A-Z]+\\s\\#\\d|[A-Z]+(\\.)?(\\s)?[A-Z]+).*" }

  def isName(line: String) : Boolean = {
    // Just to debug what's going on.
    if(line.trim.split("\\s").length == 1) {
      val x = nameRegexp.r.unapplySeq(line)
      println(s" ${x} => ${line}")
    }
    nameRegexp.r.unapplySeq(line).isDefined && line.trim.length > 0
  }

  sc.wholeTextFiles("data")
    .map(x => (x._2.split("\n")))
    .foreach(x => x.foreach(j => isName(j)))
```

Which prints out:

```
 None =>                     KYLE
 None => 
 None =>                     STAN
 None => 
 None => 
 None =>                     CARTMAN
```

Versus

```
scala> isName("                     CARTMAN")
 Some(List(CARTMAN, null, null)) =>                      CARTMAN
res11: Boolean = true
```

So when I invoke the function `isName(String)` manually or processing one file at the time, it will return true when the regular expression matches the input. However, when processing multiple files, it will anonymously return false.

Why is Spark behaving like that?

#### Clarifications

In light of the comments:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("data").map(x => (x._2.split("\n"))).foreach(x => x.foreach(j => println(s"-- $j")))
```

prints the contents of the file line by line.

```
--                     KYLE
-- 
                We can eat it at Cartman’s house and
--              see more naughty pictures of his mom!
-- 
--                        CARTMAN
--              Knock it off, you guys!! She said she
--              was young and she needed the money!!
-- 
--                        STAN
--                  (Off-screen)
--              Cartman! The pictures were taken like
--              last month!!
```

Comment: Have you checked that in the spark foreach statement (the second one) you pass the same string structure as in the scala console ?

Comment: @dumitru I have, it does print sensible information.

Comment: Don;t think so, I've just tried out your code and isName function inside the spark code receive the entire data from your file

Comment: @dumitru Check OP :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use textFile instead of wholeTextFile

```
sc.textFile("file:///d:/data.txt").map(x => x.split("\n")).flatMap(x => x).map(x => isName(x)).collect
```

Output:

```
 Some(List(CARTMAN, null, null)) =>                      CARTMAN
 Some(List(CARTMAN, null, null)) =>                      CARTMAN
 Some(List(CARTMAN, null, null)) =>                      CARTMAN
 Some(List(CARTMAN, null, null)) =>                      CARTMAN
res33: Array[Boolean] = Array(true, true, true, true)
```